# How to delete a workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, workspace

How to delete a workspace in Eclipse?

Comment: I know this seems like a simple question but the best way to pose it would have been to say what you did that didn't work (if anything), and why you're trying to do this. You might be asking the wrong question unknowingly and the more info you can provide, the better the answers you'll receive.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your suggestion. I was not really facing any specific problem in deleting a workspace; I was just curious to know if there is a way to delete the workspace from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

Just delete the whole directory. This will delete all the projects but also the Eclipse cache and settings for the workspace. These are kept in the `.metadata` folder of an Eclipse workspace. Note that you can configure Eclipse to use project folders that are *outside* the workspace folder as well, so you may want to verify the location of each of the projects.

You can remove the workspace from the suggested workspaces by going into the *General/Startup and Shutdown/Workspaces* section of the preferences (via Preferences > General > Startup & Shudown > Workspaces > [Remove] ). Note that this does not remove the files itself. For old versions of Eclipse you will need to edit the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` file in the `configuration/.settings` directory under your installation directory (or in `~/.eclipse` on Unix, IIRC).

Comment: +1 and it helps to close Eclipse before editing the prefs file.

Comment: +1 from me too for the accurate & details steps. I don't know when the `Windows` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Startup & Shudown` > `Workspaces` > `[Remove]` (button) was added either but I can confirm it exists on Indigo 3.7.2.

Comment: One comment that needs to be made is that just deleting the directories will not work, Eclipse will remake them if you don't remove it from the General -> Startup & Shutdown -> Workspaces...

Comment: @kgpdeveloper: Well you've still deleted the workspace, and the "remove from the list" is in the second paragraph. Did you follow that part as well?

Comment: I also had to edit:  
eclipse/configuration/config.ini  
osgi.instance.area=../myworkspace

Comment: "Just delete the whole directory" ...sure, if you want to delete any other workspaces that might be contained in a sub directory, along with any files you might need. I think i'll just remove it from the preferences screen, considering that is what it's there for; and refer to a "how to delete a folder in windows" tutorial if I'm trying to accomplish that.

Comment: @b1nary: If you've got one workspace embedded within another, I think you've got bigger problems. I'd strongly advise avoiding that.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're intentionally missing the point. If someone asks you how to delete fileXYZ, do you tell them to just wipe their entire drive? Of course not. Will it work? Of course! Does that make it good advice? No, because it's absurd. You're advising folks to delete any and all source, assets, etc. that they may or may not have backed up. Which is equally absurd. I think you should be more worried about the advice your handing out than with the composition of my workspace.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy: I'm certainly not "intentionally missing the point" - please don't assume you know my thoughts. I'm assuming that the reader knows where their source is, and knows whether or not they've got it backed up. You are, of course, free to add your own answer.

Comment: could have been more explicit as in : https://surfdev.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/removing-an-unwanted-workspace-from-eclipse/

Comment: The direct answer is the comment from @Withheld and it works in the latest eclipse Neon1 _Windows > Preferences > General > Startup & Shudown > Workspaces > [Remove]_

Answer (score 283):

It's possible to remove the workspace in Eclipse without much complications. The options are available under Preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown->Workspaces.

Note that this does not actually delete the files from the system, it simply removes it from the list of suggested workspaces. It changes the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` file in Jon's answer from within Eclipse.

Comment: I found that the workspace disappears from the "File -> Switch Workspace" list the next time you open Eclipse.

Comment: If you'd add that this does not cover deleting the contents of the workspace than you'd have a better, i.e. more up to date,  answer than Jon Skeet! Now, how many people can say that ;-)

Comment: Just a note, this option was introduced in Eclipse version 3.5 or 3.6

Comment: On OS X, the location of the file that is maintained by this setting is located in the application bundle itself. /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/.settings

Comment: note that Preferences is under Window on the menu bar

Answer (score 39):

For Eclipse PDT in Mac OS, once you have deleted the actual workspace directory the option to select and switch to that workspace will still be available unless you delete the entry from **Preferences** >> **General** >> **Startup and Shutdown** >> **Workspaces**.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure about older versions, but from NEON onward, you can just *right click on workspace* and select **Remove from launcher selection** option.

[image: Eclipse Neon - Remove Workspace]

*of course this won't remove the original files. It simply removes it from the list of suggested workspaces.*

Comment: +1 as this describes the place where I expected the setting to be, but since it's displayed as a link I didn't even thought of maybe right-clicking it

Answer (score 11):

Click on the menu **Window** > **Preferences** and go to **Workspaces** like below :

```
| General
    | Startup and Shutdown
        | Workspaces
```

Select the workspace to delete and click on the **Remove** button.

Comment: same answer with bananaaus

Comment: This helps me for eclipse Neon

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the \eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\configuration.settings directory and change or remove **org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs** file.