# How to delete obsolete workspace in RAD?

Tags: java, rad, workspace

How can I delete workspace in Rational Application Developer (RAD). I know deleting the folder will delete the workspace, but it still shows me in switch workspace option in RAD.

I found that edit the org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs will do it, but what is it that I should edit??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514833/how-to-delete-a-workspace-in-eclipse). It can be related since RAD is basically Eclipse (with IBM added features).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` only allows you to show `RECENT_WORKSPACES` for when you start Eclipse, it doesn't allow for deleting for the workspace.

To delete workspace, just delete the workspace directory (and remove it from `RECENT_WORKSPACES`). An explanation can be found on [EclipseZone](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t28376.html).

**Update** the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` can be found under `ECLIPSE_HOME/configuration/.settings/` directory.

Comment: the file does not show me RECENT_WORKSPACES have a look at my file #Wed Oct 13 17:13:09 EDT 2010
eclipse.preferences.version=1
TASKS_FILTERS_MIGRATE=true
tipsAndTricks=true
platformState=1284580817727
EXIT_PROMPT_ON_CLOSE_LAST_WINDOW=false
PROBLEMS_FILTERS_MIGRATE=true

Comment: I found another file with this name, and I can see RECENT_WORKSPACE, editing this solved my problem..  Thanks.